# Child update from listview in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update data from Listview by LongPress. Everything is working fine. But there is little trouble in that portion.

```
   private boolean UpdateB(String id , String tp){

        databaseBazars = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BazarList").child(id);
        Bazar bz= new Bazar(id,tp); // this line showing error.
        databaseBazars.setValue(bz);
        return  true;
    }
```

Here is the on long press alert dialog window code:

```
private void showupdatedialog(final String bid, final String cost, String da) {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.updatedialogue, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogview);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) dialogview.findViewById(R.id.updatecost);
        final Button buttonUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnupdate);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Udating Cost of Date " + da);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String et = editText.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(et)) {
                    editText.setError("Data Required");
                    return;
                }
                UpdateB(bid,et);    

            }
        });
    }
```

and there is the onlongpress listner code:

```
   listViewBazars.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           Bazar bazar = bazarList.get(i);

           showupdatedialog(bazar.getBid(),bazar.getCost(),bazar.getDate());
           return false;
       }
   });
```

Can anyone say what I did wrong on `UpdateB` portion?? Or better you suggest me a way how to update a single child.

database picture [image] and I just want to update the cost part.

Comment: We won't help you if you won't show us your exception stacktrace. Could you add it to your question?

Comment: can you just show me a method that how to update specific child from listview in firebase?

Comment: Excuse me? You asking us whats wrong with your method, saying that you getting some kind of error and not saying what kind of error it is. May you first add your stack trace, then it will be much easier to find a perfect solution for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to update do this:

```
  private boolean UpdateB(String id , String tp){
    databaseBazars = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BazarList").child(id);
    databaseBazars.child("your_child_name_here").setValue(bz);
    databaseBazars.child("your_child_name_here1").setValue(ids);
    return true;
}
```

The above is done if your database is like this:

```
BazarList
     id
       your_child_name_here: somewords
       your_chil_name_here1: somewords
```

Doing this every child will be updated on its own.

Comment: please check the edited verson . i just want to update the cost child.

Comment: its work for me. but i just did a  silly mistake i've lost last 30 days data. i'm using free verson of firebase.anyway thanks. wish i could see the solution a couple of momments ago. may be i am able to save the data . anyway thanks man. :) :)